# How do I retrieve all my posted tweets using python-twitter?

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I'm using [**python-twitter**](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) in my Web Application to post tweets like this:

```
import twitter
twitter_api = twitter.Api(
    consumer_key="BlahBlahBlah",
    consumer_secret="BlahBlahBlah",
    access_token_key="BlahBlahBlah",
    access_token_secret="BlahBlahBlah",
)
twitter_api.PostUpdate("Hello World")
```

How do I retrieve all tweets posted to this account (including tweets that were previously posted to this account from other Twitter clients)? I want to do this so that I can delete them all by calling `twitter_api.destroyStatus()` on each tweet.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be like the following:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                      consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                      access_token_key='access_token',
                      access_token_secret='access_token_secret')

# get user data from credentials
user_data = api.VerifyCredentials()

user_id = long(user_data.id)
max_status_id = 0 

# repeat until all tweets are deleted
while True:

  # let us get 200 statuses per API call. 
  # trim_user helps improve performance by reducing size of return value
  timeline_args = {'user_id': user_id, 'count': 200, 'trim_user': 'true'}

  # if not first iteration, use max_status_id seen so far
  if max_status_id != 0:
    timeline_args['max_id'] = max_status_id

  # Get statuses from user timeline
  statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(**timeline_args)

  #if no more tweets are left, then break the loop
  if statuses is None or len(statuses) == 0:
    break 

  for status in statuses:
    # remember max_status_id seen so far
    max_status_id = long(status.id) - 1

    # delete the tweet with current status[id]
    api.DestroyStatus(status.id)
```